# How to bypass warning Unexpected any. Specify a different type @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any

Tags: typescript, eslint

We have a strict zero lint issues policy. This means all errors and warnings need to be fixed.

Facing this lint error in our React typescript project:

> `warning  Unexpected any. Specify a different type  @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any`

Searched on Google and on the lint website. I didn't find a solution as such!

Tried this: `// eslint:@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any: "off"` which is not working

Does anyone know how to bypass this `eslint` rule in a React typescript project?

Comment: can you not just fix the error?

Comment: @PierreDuc No, we want to bypass this error in our case

Answer (score 42):

In Angular we add that in the TypeScript rules. Not in the general rules because sometimes that doesn't work.

Example:

```
"rules": {
             
   "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": ["off"]
}
```

In the **.eslintrc.json** file

Answer (score 30):

Following will work for you.

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
```

Check [eslint documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments)

Answer (score 22):

Something that works for me when trying to bypass the same rule, specially for overloading methods is to use:
`// eslint-disable-next-line` if you can simply just add a comment right above the line with the issue.

Or you can ignore the rule for just a section of the code by
`/* eslint-disable rule-name */ your-block-of-code /* eslint-enable rule-name */` The comments here must be block comments.

Answer (score 19):

As described by [typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v4.33.0/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/ban-types.md):

- If you want a type meaning "any object", you probably want `Record<string, unknown>` instead.
- If you want a type meaning "any value", you probably want `unknown` instead

In fact you can often replace any with a better option. For that you can use Record type as mentioned by [@RollingInTheDeep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69449844/12975352) or you can use index signature like:

```
{[key1: string]: number | unknown} // object.x = number | unknown
{[key2: string]: {[key3:string]: number | undefined}} | boolean // object.x can be a boolean or another object that contains key strings with numeric or undefined values
```

Answer (score 18):

Can you use `unknown`? e.g. `HttpResponse<unknown>`

Comment: +1. This seems to work. However, in cases when a method using any is overridden (example: an Angular HttpInterceptor which has the function `intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>;`), the override has different types from the base.

Answer (score 12):

"@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": ["off"]

Comment: You can elaborate your answare to clarify why this approach will solve the issue

Answer (score 6):

If your expecting (key, value) pairs in an object, but dont know what the keys may be you can define a type as below.  Where someObject is unknown, but instead of using any use the Record<string, unknown> eslint is fine with this.

```
    type MyType = {
        name: string;
        someObject: Record<string, unknown>;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

add this rule in your .eslintrc.json file

`"rules": { "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off" }`

Answer (score 0):

use getAdditionalInfo method.

```
import {  signInWithPopup, getAdditionalUserInfo } from "firebase/auth";

function signInWithGoogleAuth() {
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
        .then(async (result) => {
            const isFirstLogin = getAdditionalUserInfo(result).isNewUser
         }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
rules:
  "no-explicit-any": ["off"]
  NOT "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": ["off"]
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35155030)

Comment: Hello I don't understand your coment ?