# Turn `@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any` off

Tags: typescript, eslint

In `eslintrc.cjs`

```
 rules: {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off"
 }
```

Still reports warnings..

```
warning  Unexpected any. Specify a different type  @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
```

How do I turn this rule off!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bypass warning Unexpected any. Specify a different type @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58467000/how-to-bypass-warning-unexpected-any-specify-a-different-type-typescript-eslin)

Answer (score 0):

You must stop **(crtl+C)** in terminal of your app and start it again after set this rule off